# google maps API v3 not showing up in browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a bit of a problem with my Google Maps application.

So I'm following the code given on the API to create the basic map. I have this:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #map { height: 75% }
 </style>
```

And i have the following javascript as well to initialize the map:

```
function showmap(coordinates)
{
    var lat = coordinates.latitude;
    var lon = coordinates.longitude;

    var myOptions = {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}
```

but all I get in the browser is just a big gray box. I've tried in several browsers (chrome, firefox etc...) but it all looks the same. I'm pretty sure I've set it up correctly...anybody got any ideas what's happening?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Any errors reported in the javascript console (devtools, firebug, etc.)?

Comment: nope, javascript console is completely clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the position-parameter is good for(there is no map-option like this), but I guess you mixed up `position` and `center`(`center` is required)